# RcppArmadillo: Complex matrix inverse compilation error

Tags: r, matrix, rcpp

I am trying to invert a complex square matrix using RcppArmadillo:

```
# include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
cx_mat fn(cx_mat x) {
  return x.i();
}
```

However, this throws an error when I `sourceCpp` it: 
"undefined reference to `zgetri_'`". It compiles and works fine if I just replace `cx_mat` with `mat`, but then it will only work with real matrices. Using `inv()` throws the same compilation error. Interestingly, using the pseudo-inverse `pinv()` passes compilation, but the result would be slightly different compared with R's `solve()`:

```
# include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
cx_mat fn(cx_mat x) {
  return pinv(x);
}

> a<-matrix(c(3+0.1i,7+2i,4+0i,2+0.5i),ncol=2)
> a
       [,1]   [,2]
[1,] 3+0.1i 4+0.0i
[2,] 7+2.0i 2+0.5i
> identical(solve(a), fn(a))
[1] FALSE
> solve(a) - fn(a)
                           [,1]                       [,2]
[1,] -6.938894e-17-7.80626e-18i  8.326673e-17-6.93889e-18i
[2,]  1.665335e-16+1.95156e-17i -1.665335e-16+4.16334e-17i
```

I know the difference is flirting with machine precision in this case, but I am still wondering if there is anyway to get `inv()` or `.i()` to work on complex matrices. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to invert the product of mat with t(conjugate(mat))? I do wonder if a more informative, cautionary error message might be helpful.

Comment: It is a compile/link failure which the OP did not show.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a known issue *if and when you use RcppArmadillo with an R installation using Rlapack.so* as for example on Windows or some RedHat systems.

The best answers are to either

- not use complex-valued functions not included as Rlapack [has some](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/modules/lapack/README) but sadly not all (but you may not have a choice)
- reconfigure you R installation to use an full external liblapack.so

We have three open tickets [at the RcppArmadillo repo](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/issues) (and in fact I even added one today listing [the twelve missing complex functions](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/issues/73) used by Armadillo but missing in Rlapack.so), and I just pleaded with R Core to add more complex-valued functions to Rlapack.

And just to stress the second point, your example works fine here as I do not use Rlapack on the Debian/Ubuntu builds:

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/aenima.cpp")

R> a <- matrix(c(3+0.1i,7+2i,4+0i,2+0.5i),ncol=2)

R> fn(a)
                      [,1]                [,2]
[1,] -0.0898473+0.0029949i  0.167715-0.047919i
[2,]  0.3174603+0.0000000i -0.126984+0.031746i
R>
```

using a slightly modified version of your file with the example at the end:

```
# include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
cx_mat fn(cx_mat x) {
  return x.i();
}

/*** R
a <- matrix(c(3+0.1i,7+2i,4+0i,2+0.5i),ncol=2)
fn(a)
*/
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am running this on Windows 8.1 with the default R installation. I think I will have to live with `pinv` for now. I hope the error propagation will stay trivial in my application as this matrix inverse is only the starting point of my application.